# Positioning an image on the side of a list

Tags: graphics, floats, lists

I'm making a geometry test, which has many enumerated questions with 4 alternatives each one,and the idea is to insert the figure on the right of the alternatives which are on the left but I'm not having success on it.

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{{\large \textbf{\textsf{\Alph*)}}}}]
            \item $95$
            \item $96$
            \item $99$
            \item $100$
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{flushright}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{im1.pdf} 
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two side-by-side minipages you can achieve the following output. (Red lines indicate the margins)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{{\large \textbf{\textsf{\Alph*)}}}}]
            \item $95$
            \item $96$
            \item $99$
            \item $100$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \flushright
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image} 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```